# ZF2: Zend Framework 2 Full URL including host name

Tags: zend-framework2

In my view I need to draw full URL. Like this:

```
http://hostename.com/default/url
```

When I try to use `$this->url('default', array(1,2,3))` I get only `/index/get/`. Is there any Zend method to het host name or I have to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead?

Answer (score 45):

You can use the option `force_canonical` on the router. All router options go into the third parameter of the url helper:

```
url($route, $params, $options)
```

So you can so something like this:

```
$this->url('myroute', array('id' => 123), array('force_canonical' => true))
```

Comment: This functionality isn't referenced anywhere in the documentation and I think it's quite a common thing. Do you know how to also force it to use https for instance? I would have expected to use something like 'scheme' => 'https' as a parameter or option but it doesn't seem to be that easy

Comment: @DominicWatson I am not sure if there's an option to set the scheme. I create a https url by using Zend\Url\Http like this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122535/how-to-forced-https-instead-of-http-after-user-login-in-zend-framework2/20125800#20125800

Answer (score 26):

I found this [article](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/create-full-urls-in-zf2-views) with some interesting ways:

**1)** without parameters use an empty array:

```
// Using a route with the name "register" and the route "/register"
echo $this->url('register', array(), array('force_canonical' => true)); 
// Output: http://mydomain.com/register
```

**2)** note the differences between:

```
echo $this->serverUrl(); 
// Output: http://mydomain.com
```

and

```
// Current URL: http://mydomain.com/register
echo $this->serverUrl(true); 
// Output: http://mydomain.com/register
```

**3)** starting from the route

```
// The "register" route has the following route: /register
echo $this->serverUrl($this->url('register')); 
// Output: http://mydomain.com/register
```

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME DEAR, IT WORKS LIKE CHARM :)

Answer (score 14):

There is a Zend\View\Helper\ServerUrl to create full url in zend view.
Try below code in your view template.

```
<?php echo $this->serverUrl()?>
```

Comment: The question is about generate full url in the view. But if someone get here looking for how to do it in the controller, here it is:
`$this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_HOST') . $this->url()->fromRoute('carrinho/compra-efetuada')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set base URL globally, you can do it using onBootstrap method:

```
$e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouter()->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);
```

In this case Navigation helpers would also use it.

To fetch current base URL use ServerUrl helper as described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079460/base-url-of-zend-framework-2):

```
$serverUrl = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('ServerUrl');
$baseUrl = $serverUrl->__invoke();
```

Comment: "$serverUrl->__invoke();" ?? Isn't "__invoke()" made to be able to run it as "$serverUrl()" ?