# how to forced https instead of http after user login in zend framework2

Tags: https, zend-framework2

I want user redirect to https insetad of http just after login in my new website made in zend framework2. please help.

I there any method available in zend freamework2 to get current used protocol(http or https).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the user to the https version of a page inside the application. Above solution simply redirects *all* requests to it's http variant, and only for Apache. I would rather do it inside the application (then you're more in control) and make it server agnostic (what happens when you switch to nginx?)

An example is based on an answer I gave earlier here: [ZF2 and force HTTPS for specific routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141140/zf2-and-force-https-for-specific-routes)

The solution: create a controller plugin which you can call every time you need it.
Specify the pages you need to force a redirect (i.e. the page you show the login form):

```
use Zend\Http\Response;

public function loginAction()
{
    // If return value is response, this means the user will be redirected
    $result = $this->forceHttps();
    if ($result instanceof Response) {
        return $result;
    }

    // code here
}
```

And then you could create a controller plugin (call it `ForceHttps`) to return a response when the user should be redirected:

```
use Zend\Uri\Http as HttpUri;

class ForceHttps extends AbstractPlugin
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $request = $this->getController()->getRequest();

        if ('https' === $request->getUri()->getScheme()) {
            return;
        }

        // Not secure, create full url
        $plugin = $this->getController()->url();
        $string = $plugin->fromRoute(null, array(), array(
            'force_canonical' => true,
        ), true);

        $url = new HttpUri($string);
        $url->setScheme('https');

        return $this->getController()->redirect()->toUrl($url);
    }
}
```

What happens is

1. Check if the current scheme is https. If not, continue
2. Grab the current used url from the url() plugin, use the current route name (hence the first parameter is `null`), force the canonical version (i.e. with a full scheme and domain name) and reuse the current route match parameters (the `true` as last parameter).
3. Import the url (as a string) in the Zend\Url\Http object
4. Reset the scheme to the https version
5. Pass the url to the redirect plugin to grab a response which will perform the redirect

Answer (score 0):

on your `.htaccess` write these rules

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

note that `public/index.php` is the root so you have to modify it and `www.yoursite.com` too

for `logged-in user` you have to do with `php`

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if($auth->hasIdentity()) {//redirection should be here//}
```

Comment: I want to apply this rule only after user logged in my website not all time.

Comment: @manan the SSL it is used to protect user creditentials and business information so after logged in ....

Comment: yes you are right, but i want to apply https at login page, once user logged in then after every page where user visit.

Comment: @manan you have to add condition that is special for user logged cookie or querystring

Comment: So you want to skip ssl in most important step when user sends username and password?