# Base Url of Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to get **Base URL** in controller of Zend Framework 2 to pass as value of src attributes of img tag.I put my image in public folder.

How can I get **Base URL** in controller of Zend Framework 2 ??

Comment: Why not just use an absolute path? `<img src="/image/foo.jpg">`?

Comment: @TimFountain using full url may be handy, for exemple, you render a html mail with your company logo without sending image.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [ServerUrl](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/ServerUrl.php) view helper for **absolute** URL's and [BasePath](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-view/helpers/base-path/) for the **relative** ones in any view.

```
$this->serverUrl();             // output: http://your.domain.com
$this->serverUrl('/foo');       // output: http://your.domain.com/foo
$this->basePath();              // output: /
$this->basePath('img/bar.png'); // output: /img/bar.png
```

**Edit:** Oh sorry, question was about getting that value in controller level, not view. In any controller you can do this:

```
$helper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('ServerUrl');
$url = $helper->__invoke('/foo');
// or
$url = $helper('/foo');
```

**Update for Zend Framework 3**

Since controllers are not [ServiceLocatorAware](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/pull/36) by default in ZF3, you need to inject the helper instance to your controller, preferably using a factory.

For rookies, an example factory may look like:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class ExampleActionFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Factories are invokable
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $dic
     * @param string             $requestedName
     * @param array|null         $options
     *
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     *
     * @return ExampleAction
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $dic, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $helper = $dic->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('ServerUrl');

        return new ExampleAction($helper);
    }
}
```

and a constructor signature on controller something like:

```
/**
 * @var ServerUrl
 */
private $urlHelper;

public function __construct(ServerUrl $helper)
{
    $this->urlHelper = $helper;
}
```

Comment: The question was effectively to get baseUrl in controller, but it's indeed a better practice to use it in the view.

Comment: Nice one. Been using ZF2 since beta-whatever and didn't even know about this helper. Always ended up concatenating protocols and hostnames.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question about ZF3

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [BasePath Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.base-path.html) in your view.

And if it is for setting the `src` attribute of an image, no need to set it at controller level.