# how to get current url and base path in my view helper function using zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, helper

This function is in helper I am using zf2 version 2.4 I am beginner in zend please help me. 
I tried this:

```
function getUrlArray(){
     $helperUrl = new Url(); //  use Zend\View\Helper\Url;
     $op =   $helperUrl->url();
     print_r($op); 
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method   Zend\View\Helper\Url::url()

Comment: what do you want achieve and where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base Url of Zend Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079460/base-url-of-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ViewHelper :

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\View\Helper\Service;

use YourNamespace\View\Helper\CurrentUri;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class CurrentUriFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return CurrentUri
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $helper = new CurrentUri();
        $helper->setRequest($serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Request'));
        return $helper;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

/**
 * Helper: $this->currentUri();
 */
class CurrentUri extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @return string
     * @see \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request
     * @see \Zend\Uri\Uri
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->getUri()->toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request
     */
    public function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->request;
    }

    /**
     * @param  RequestInterface $request
     * @return CurrentUri
     */
    public function setRequest(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        return $this;
    }
}
```