# How to send base path in Zend 2 framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

i am new in zend 2. i have run this  application it can be properly work but access the other page or controller it can be give 404 error....

```
http://localhost/Gojavas/public/
```

[image]

Click on the login button

> http://localhost/branch/login

automatic remove the main folder in url.....and display the 404 page error...please help me....thanx

> Htaccess File

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /Gojavas/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

```
 <ifmodule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22079626/1697459) on another related question.

Comment: It really looks as a `.htaccess` issue. Is the 404 page the ZF2 error page ?  What is your root `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Please check my .htaccess file i am change my que..

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

... means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then procede to the rewrite rule below

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```